# Please tell me how to create an object if the name is stored in a variable

Tags: actionscript-3

Please tell me how to create an object if the name is stored in a variable.

```
var className:String = 'Config';
var MySprite:Sprite = new ???

class Config extends Sprite {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var configClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("Config") as Class;
var configInstance:Config = new configClass as Config;
```

EDIT: Aurel300 has a point. Statically typing to an **exact** class is senseless, simply because if you can explicitly code the exact type of what it is going to be, then you might as well create a class as per normal.

That being said, you will probably have somewhat of an idea of what the type could be, for example if you are dealing with audio you know it will inherit from Sound, or images you know it will inherit from Sprite. So in those cases best practise would be to statically type it as the lowest common base class. If it can be literally any class then there is no point in statically typing it at all, but I can not think of any useful reason why you would create classes that could be anything.

So if you are expecting the type to be Config or classes that inherit from Config then the code above is correct. Otherwise my guess is that you are expecting classes that extend Sprite (so you can add them to stage perhaps) so then you would change it to:

```
var configClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("Config") as Class;
var configInstance:Sprite= new configClass as Sprite;
```

Comment: The second line is kinda bad - you don't know whether or not it will be Config - and you used that two times. I think it would be better to just use no strong-type AND no dynamic-cast. That would be "var configInstance = new configClass();"

Comment: @Aurel300 - hmm not really. Where possible you should use static typing. If for some reason the class returned by getDefinitionByName wasn't what you were after then you would be better off receiving an error and fixing the problem. That said, the 'as' wont throw an error but return null, so a check for null would be required.

Comment: The whole problem in this is that we need something, that is defined ONLY by name - it can be anything. Therefore stating "Config" later in the code renders all the dynamic useless, as we could simply do "new Config()" - here we can not, so we can also not do ":Config" or " as Config".

Comment: @Aurel300 - Ok, now I see where you are coming from =), you are suggesting that, for example, if we were reading in an unknown XML file that contained strings to create classes from, then statically typing is pointless because we can not possibly know what the XML file might be telling us to create.

Comment: @Aurel300. I think I get your point. However, if you don't know anything about your object, how could you possibly do something useful with it? In most cases, you make a few assumptions, at least. You don't expect just any kind of obejct. IMO, this kink of pattern is useful when you dynamically create an instance the is a subtype of a known type (so you'd type your instance as some base class or interface).

Comment: It is useful. When you have more possible types, all extending one class. It WOULD be possible to use that original class that they were extended from, but just in case it does not...

Comment: Ditto what Juan said. There is no reason why you would code to expect ANY class because you HAVE to assume something about it otherwise you can not possibly call any functions on the instance or pass it as a parameter to a function that expects a certain type. Simply put, the class would be of no use. That is why you WILL know a common base type, because no matter what the exact class is, you can call those base type functions as they are going to exist.

Comment: ...(continued) If you did get a different base class (say we forgot to inherit) then you are better off catching the error as early as possible rather then let is manifest in your program thereby making it harder to find. By statically typing (strong typing is something different) you improve code readability, have type safety and receive a slight performance improvement :)